# Visual Studio Code offline installation

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a possibility to instal "Visual Studio Code" **offline** ? (with no Internet connection)

Best Regards

Comment: Please provide some additional information here to help us investigate. VSCode normally works when you download and install.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily download the official installer from
https://code.visualstudio.com/download# (I took the System Installer version)
Therefore download the binaries on another machine.

Extensions can be installed from visx file.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.powershell
extension name can bee looked up in VSCode itself:
[VS Code extension identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHbJr.png)

Then install the extension.
[where to find the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo9nm.png)

That should be IMHO enough.

You surely already managed to install VS Code. For people who google a solution this could be helpful.